# Zoom using discrete Fourier transform and zero padding in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fft, zooming

I am trying to make image zoom using DFT (discrete Fourier transform ) in opencv c++. The concept is to make and DFT to an image then add zero border to it then do the inverse of DFT. I encountered a problem in the result. I would guess it is in padding the result of DFT with zero. Here is my code. Anyone who has an idea how to solve it, please help me and thanks is advance.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void calculeDFT(Mat& source , Mat& destination)
{

    Mat origincomplex [2] = {source , Mat::zeros(source.size(),CV_32F)};

    Mat dtfready;

    merge(origincomplex, 2, dtfready);

    Mat origindft;

    dft(dtfready, origindft , DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

    destination = origindft ;

}
void Ajoutbor(Mat& source, Mat& destination)
{
    copyMakeBorder(source,source,50,50,50,50, BORDER_CONSTANT,0);

    Mat splitTab[2] = {Mat::zeros(source.size(),CV_32F),Mat::zeros(source.size(),CV_32F)};

    split(source,splitTab);

    //Mat dftMag;

    copyMakeBorder(splitTab[0],splitTab[0],50,50,50,50, BORDER_CONSTANT,0);

    copyMakeBorder(splitTab[1],splitTab[1],50,50,50,50, BORDER_CONSTANT,0);

    merge(splitTab, 2 , destination);

    //magnitude(splitTab[0], splitTab[1], dftMag);

    //dftMag += Scalar::all(1);

    //log(dftMag, dftMag);

    //normalize(dftMag, dftMag, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);

    //CenterDFT(dftMag);

    //imshow("DFT",dftMag);

    //destination = dftMag ;

    waitKey();

}

void CenterDFT(Mat& source)
{
    int cx = source.cols/2;
    int cy = source.rows/2;

    Mat q0(source, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));
    Mat q1(source, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));
    Mat q2(source, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));
    Mat q3(source, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy));

    Mat tmp;
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);

}
void afficheDFT(Mat& source)
{
    Mat splitTab[2] = {Mat::zeros(source.size(),CV_32F),Mat::zeros(source.size(),CV_32F)};

    split(source,splitTab);

    Mat dftMag;

    magnitude(splitTab[0], splitTab[1], dftMag);

    dftMag += Scalar::all(1);

    log(dftMag, dftMag);

    normalize(dftMag, dftMag, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);

    CenterDFT(dftMag);

    imshow("DFT",dftMag);

    waitKey();

}

void InverseDFT(Mat& source,Mat& destination)
{
    Mat inverse;

    dft(source, inverse, DFT_INVERSE | DFT_REAL_OUTPUT | DFT_SCALE);

    destination = inverse ;

}
int main()
{


Mat img = imread("bn.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat imgfloat;

img.convertTo(imgfloat ,CV_32FC1 , 1.0 /255.0);

imshow("Image Original",imgfloat);

Mat imgdft;

calculeDFT(imgfloat,imgdft);

Mat imgap;



afficheDFT(imgdft);

Ajoutbor(imgdft,imgap);

Mat inversdft;

InverseDFT(imgap,inversdft);


imshow("inverse ", inversdft);

cvWaitKey();

}
```

Here is how is looks:

[image]

Comment: I don't have a setup to validate this, but it likely should go along the line of `calculeDFT` -> `centerDFT` -> `Ajoutbor` -> `centerDFT` -> `InverseDFT`. This would ensure the zeros are added to the "high-frequency" areas of the image in the frequency-domain to obtain the desired spatial-domain interpolation.

Comment: Thank you so much , it works